# Elasticsearch nest c# compiler error

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to test creating an index, add a document and search for it with a filter. I'm getting a compiler error that i can't seem to resolve. Thanks for your help!

Compiler Error (VS 2013, Console App):

"An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation."

When I double click on the error, it will highlight "t.User" in the .Filter line of code.

Here's the full code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nest;

namespace elastic_search_client_app
{
    class Post
    {
        public int Id;

        public string User;

        public DateTime PostDate;

        public String Message;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://es-server-name"); 

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).SetDefaultIndex("stack-overflow-posts");

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var post = new Post() { Id = 2, User = "mk@microsoft.com", PostDate = DateTime.Now, Message = "This is pretty cool and lot of text stuff here from catalog summary collection" };

            client.Index(post);

            client.Refresh();

            var result = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
                .Index("stack-overflow-posts")
                .AllTypes()
                .Query(q =>
                    q.QueryString(qs =>
                        qs.Query("cool")))
                .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.User, "mk@microsoft.com")));
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.
```

The error is pretty straight forward.

The compiled filter query expression `t => t.User, "mk@microsoft.com"` has a signature of `Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldDescriptor, object term)`.

The compiler cannot deduce `T` because the `T` is of type `dynamic`.

You can either change the type of the query to `client.Search<Post>` or use the `string` overload.

```
var result = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
    .Index("stack-overflow-posts")
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q =>
        q.QueryString(qs =>
            qs.Query("cool")))
    .Filter(f => f.Term("user", "mk@microsoft.com")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! But, I haven't got it to work completely yet.

I changed the code to the following and it works:

```
var result = client.Search<Post>(s => s
                                .Index("stack-overflow-posts")
                                .AllTypes()
                                .Query(q =>
                                    q.QueryString(qs =>
                                        qs.Query("cool")))
                                .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.Id, 2)));
```

But the code below doesn't and gives 0 results. What's wrong with my code?

```
var result = client.Search<Post>(s => s
                      .Index("stack-overflow-posts")
                      .AllTypes()
                      .Query(q =>
                             q.QueryString(qs =>
                                          qs.Query("cool")))
                      .Filter(f => f.Term(t => t.User, "mk@microsoft.com")));
```